# htaccess - the page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my site using htaccess but it is showing

> the page isn't redirecting properly.

```
RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wavenetcorp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.wavenetcorp\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/wavenetcorp\.com\/wavenet" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are having an infinite/recursive redirection. Your domain A is redirection to Domain B and it is in turn redirecting to Domain A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the WordPress URL to wavenetcorp.com/wavenet so it won't be redirect back to the wrong URL.

Normally you don't have to add the htaccess redirect after this. WordPress will take care of it.